# generate pdf from json array objects with proper tabular format

Tags: node.js, pdf, aws-lambda

I want to generate pdf from json array using node.js and i want these in aws lambda with node.js.i have used many libraries but id doesn't work can you please guide me how can i acheive this

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/pdf/', function (req, res, next) {
    var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    var json = { list: ['Test', 'Array'], success: true }
    doc.fontSize(15)
        .fillColor('blue')
        .text(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2), 100, 100)
    // .link(100, 100, 160, 27, link);

    doc.pipe(res);

    doc.end();
});
```

We can use [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit) node module and [JSON.stringfy](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

**Result:**
[image]